# Ubuntu 20.04.1 Boot error: “/dev/sda2 does not exist. Dropping to shell.”

Tags: boot, system-installation, 20.04, initramfs, busybox

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on my old PC (Sony VAIO Fit 15A) using a configured live USB. While installing I kept all recommended settings and did not check the box to download third party applications.

I am completely new to the world of Linux and I wanted to use this PC to get into it.

That being said, when I boot up my PC and choose "Ubuntu" from the list in the GNU GRUB screen I get the following error:

```
Gave up waiting for root file system devices. Common problems:
     - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
            -Check rootdelay=(did the system wait long enough?)
     - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/sda2 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

And then a `BusyBox` built-in shell appears.

After 4 hours of trying to search online for some solutions and with the lack of experience I have with Linux I wasn't able to neither understand or solve the issue. (I tried performing a fresh installation of Ubuntu twice but the problem still persists)

Is there any way this can be fixed?

Please let me know what kind of extra information I can supply to make it easier.

Comment: You mist have done something else to get there. This means that the system can't find the boot partition.

Comment: @Pilot6 Do you know how can I solve this?

Comment: The easiest way is to do a fresh install. It is not straight forward from here.

Comment: @Pilot6 Unfortunately this didn't work, I forgot to mention it earlier. My question is editted now.